# jetty 9 and intellij won't start

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty

I'm playing around with intellij for a new project and am having a bit of a problem.  When I try to run jetty 9 from intellij 12, I get this error

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin\java" -DSTOP.PORT=0 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -DOPTIONS=jmx -Didea.launcher.port=7553 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "start.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main etc/jetty-jmx.xml C:\Users\willie\AppData\Local\Temp\context9038140457899104277config\jetty-contexts.xml
[2013-02-17 01:49:18,784] Artifact Armor:war exploded: Server is not connected. Press 'Deploy' to start deployment.
2013-02-17 01:49:20.055:WARN:oejx.XmlParser:main: FATAL@file:/C:/Code/jetty-9.0.0.RC0/start.d/ line:1 col:1 : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Code/jetty-9.0.0.RC0/start.d/; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Code/jetty-9.0.0.RC0/start.d/; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1388)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:998)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1209)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1160)
    ... 12 more

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information

Process finished with exit code -2
Disconnected from server
```

This is with the base system.  I have deleted the profile, recreated it, I've downloaded another copy of jetty, I've done everything I can think of. The curious thing is the only thing in the start.d folder is the default test ini file that came with the distribution.  I opened the xml file that ini file references and there is nothing wrong with it.  I'm completely stumped.  Does anyone know what could be going on here?

Update, 
jetty runs just fine from the command line, but not from Intellij

Update 2, It seems that the way IntelliJ does its deployments is thru the plugin, it creates a new jetty-contexts.xml file.  That file seems to be what is not liked by jetty.  here is the file

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" id="Server">
    <Ref id="DeploymentManager">
        <Call name="addAppProvider">
            <Arg>
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ContextProvider">
                    <Set name="monitoredDir">C:\Users\willie\AppData\Local\Temp\context7950837742823871110deploy</Set>
                    <Set name="scanInterval">1</Set>
                </New>
            </Arg>
        </Call>
    </Ref>
</Configure>
```

and a new dump, now that i've deleted the test wars and removed the start.d from the config.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin\java" -DSTOP.PORT=0 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -DOPTIONS=jmx -Didea.launcher.port=7538 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "start.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main etc/jetty-jmx.xml C:\Users\willie\AppData\Local\Temp\context826007528789372946config\jetty-contexts.xml
[2013-02-17 05:38:31,987] Artifact Armor:war exploded: Server is not connected. Press 'Deploy' to start deployment.
2013-02-17 05:38:33.509:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error at <Call name="addAppProvider"><Arg>|????<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ContextProvider"><Set name="monitoredDir">C:\Users\willie\AppData\Local\Temp\context7950837742823871110deploy</Set><Set name="scanInterval">1</Set></New>|???</Arg></Call> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ContextProvider in file:/C:/Users/willie/AppData/Local/Temp/context826007528789372946config/jetty-contexts.xml
2013-02-17 05:38:33.510:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error at <Ref id="DeploymentManager"><Call name="addAppProvider"><Arg>|????<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ContextProvider"><Set name="monitoredDir">C:\Users\willie\AppData\Local\Temp\context7950837742823871110deploy</Set><Set name="scanInterval">1</Set></New>|???</Arg></Call></Ref> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ContextProvider in file:/C:/Users/willie/AppData/Local/Temp/context826007528789372946config/jetty-contexts.xml
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ContextProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.nodeClass(XmlConfiguration.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.itemValue(XmlConfiguration.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.value(XmlConfiguration.java:1016)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.call(XmlConfiguration.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.refObj(XmlConfiguration.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1160)
    ... 12 more

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of `org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main` is meant for use from a full and complete jetty distribution.

It is just a bootstrap to establish the correct classpath and configuration xmls that will eventually start Jetty.

Your command line could (I have not tested this) look like this instead ...

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin\java" 
  -Djetty.home=C:\path\to\jetty\distribution
  -DSTOP.PORT=0 
  -Didea.launcher.port=7553 
  "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4\bin"
  -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252
  -jar start.jar
  "-Dpath=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4\lib\idea_rt.jar"
  org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main
```

Note that you will likely need the following ...

- To define `jetty.home` property so that jetty knows where to look for its files
- To have the extra IntelliJ jars defined via the `-Dpath=${classpath}` configurable that jetty will pass through into the running server
- To have the IntelliJ properties defined in the `${jetty.home}/start.ini`
- To have the `OPTIONS` command line defined in the `${jetty.home/start.ini`
- To have the various jmx properties defined in the `${jetty.home}/start.ini`
- Put your custom `jetty-context.xml` into the `${jetty.home}/webapps/` directory, or change the deployment directory (in the `etc/jetty-deploy.xml`) to where your jetty-context.xml file is located.  Be sure that the reference to the war file make sense.

Finally, know that you can ask jetty what the server classpath will look like easily enough with the command line option `--version` which will list the classpath the server will use (in the order that the server will use it) based on what you have configured for the start bootstrap process.